SSAS Tabular Model Slow
Hi I have a SSAS tabular model of almost 2 GB size. I refresh it's data using Azure Analysis Service on S1 tier(P.S. I have tried with S2 tier too but it still consume same amount of time) and refresh request is generated through ADF. Earlier it was working fine and refreshing data with 40 mins for all requested partitions. Now someone has added few new DAX measures to my model and since then me refresh time has increased to 3 hours. I want to optimize my model and reduce refresh time. I am only refreshing the relevant data(current data not the historical data). How can I reduce refresh time and optimize my tabular model.
I tried reducing the data but still its taking long time to process the data which is not the ideal case. I guess the effectiveness is effected due to any DAX measure addition but still its just a guess. I dont know the method to identify the cause as I have too many DAX measures in my model.
